# Segmentation Fault 11 and trouble creating/printing an array of strings in c

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I am working on a project that will require me to keep an array of the 10 most recently entered commands from a user, and created a small test program to ensure I could actually create an array of 10 strings and print it back out. The code copied below generates "Segmentation fault: 11" when run, even though it compiles with no warnings or errors. I am very new to c and I know that this task will require some combination of pointers to arrays of characters, but I cannot seem to get it working. What do I need to do to be able to overwrite the string at any of the 10 indices in 'history' and print the current history array out by calling printFullHistory()?

```
void printFullHistory(char** history){
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(history); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < sizeof(history)[i]; j++){
            printf("%s", history[i][j]);
        }
    }
}//end printFullHistory

int main(){
    char* history[10];
    strcpy(history[0], "ls");
    printFullHistory(history);
    return 0;
}//end main
```

Comment: Read about the `sizeof` operator, and what is `sizeof(history)[i]`

Comment: Think about change function to `void printFullHistory(char** history, size_t rows, size_t cols)`

Comment: This is homework, I think

Comment: Also see [How to find the 'sizeof'(a pointer pointing to an array)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array)

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof` being one of your issues, this is also wrong:

```
char* history[10];
strcpy(history[0], "ls");
```

`history[0]` is not initialized to point to valid memory, you can't write to it.

And besides:

```
printf("%s", history[i][j]);
```

`history[i][j]` refers to j-th letter of i-th string, so maybe you wanted to use `%c`. Nevertheless, you can't print values of uninitialized variables. If you do, this is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Two main problems:

1. You `strcpy()` to an uninitialized pointer, that invokes undefined behavior. Your need to make the pointer point to valid memory. Either by using `malloc()`/`free()` or by making the array two dimensional.
2. You are using the `sizeof` operator to determine the size of an array through a pointer to the array, that's wrong. When the operand of `sizeof` is a pointer the result if the size of the pointer namely `sizeof(void *)` which is not the size of the array. You can pass the size to the function or, you can add a `NULL` pointer at the end of the array and iterate until you find it, just the same concept used for strings in [c](/questions/tagged/c).